# MSTest cannot find TestAdapter.dll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I'm using the built-in Visual Studio test tools (`Test -> Run -> etc` in the menu).  I just started having a problem where I get the following error when I try to run tests

`[3/29/2018 1:39:14 PM Error] System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\brubin\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18/build/_common/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestPlatformProvider.PerformShadowCopy(IEnumerable'1 testExtensions)`

That's followed by some errors that say

`Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.`

When I look at the folder `C:\Users\brubin\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.18/build/_common/`, there are no files in that folder.  However, I haven't knowingly changed anything about my test setup and this was working several days ago, so I don't know why it would have stopped working.

My projects are using the MSTest.TestFramework (MSTest V2) version v1.2 NuGet package.

One thing I noticed that may have caused this problem is that if I go to `Tools -> Extensions and Updates`, I see that my Microsoft Visual Studio Test Platform was updated a few days ago, on 3/23 (I think that's when I installed a Visual Studio update).  However, if that broke something, I have no idea where to look to see what's broken, or how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For me, clearing the `VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions` folder and restarting Visual Studio (as per [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/324#issuecomment-349932232)) did the trick. In my case, it contained two folders for different versions of `MSTest.TestAdapter`, I don't know whether or not that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I did that and cleared my `bin` and `obj` folders, and that fixed it.

Comment: This worked, the `VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions` folder was in  `%temp%` and requires all instance of Visual Studio to be closed before deleting.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this - cleared all contents in VisuialStudioTestExplorerExtensions folder and restart brought my tests pack in the explorer.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who stumbles on this question, the problem was caused because a few of my test projects didn't have the MSTest.TestAdapter NuGet package included.  I added the MSTest.TestAdapter package to all of my test projects, and the problem seems to be solved permanently now.

Answer (score 3):

I spent the whole last week trying to solve the same issue. Only yesterday did I realize that running tests from the console is a time saver. Much to my surprise, I've just moved all my project -which was inside a "OneDrive" folder, to a different location. Now, it works like a charm! All my tests run from the Visual Studio IDE. I don't know if moving the files had anything to do with it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Never thought OneDrive will be culprit.

Comment: This was the fix for me, thank you!. I moved my repo outside of the OneDrive folder and now my tests run fine. The error I was getting was:


"Failed to load extensions from file '...\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll'."


Maybe the problem had to do with the path containing a space.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling all solution's Nuget packages fixed this issue for me.

Please run this command on the package console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

then try again, or restart VS, then try again.

Reference: https://ardalis.com/force-nuget-to-reinstall-packages-without-updating/

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Visual Studio. Upgrade the Visual Studio to version 15.7.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/222892/filenotfoundexception-microsoftvisualstudiotestpla.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to update "MsTest.TestAdapter" on all testprojects. The easiest way is to rightclick on master solution and click on manage nuget-packages. Then select " installed " tab and see if there is installed TestAdapter on each testprojects. If necessary you can update TestAdapter to newest version. Then restart Visual Studio and it should work.